# Generalize a query to fetch all the data for a given range

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a select query which selects data between two date/time periods as below

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE table1 .row_creation > TO_DATE ('2017-04-03 11:00:00 AM','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss pm')
AND table1 .row_creation   < TO_DATE('2017-04-04 03:00:00 AM','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss pm')
AND NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT *
  FROM table1
  WHERE                    <cond>
  AND table1 .row_creation > TO_DATE ('2017-04-03 11:00:00 AM','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss pm')
  AND table1 .row_creation < TO_DATE('2017-04-04 03:00:00 AM','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss pm')
  )
```

I want to modify this query to fetch the data for all consecutive weekdays in a month in one shot. Can anyone give me some guidance?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  A description of the time frames would also give other people some context on what you are trying to do.

Comment: You need a correlated subquery, i.e. add conditions using outer table conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Add more columns in group by clause if you whant.

`SELECT TO_CHAR(row_creation,'W')
FROM table1
WHERE 
     table1 .row_creation between TO_DATE ('2017-04-03 11:00:00 AM','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss pm') AND TO_DATE('2017-04-04 03:00:00 AM','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss pm')
AND NOT EXISTS 
  ( SELECT *
    FROM table1
    WHERE
    AND table1.row_creation BETWEEN TO_DATE ('2017-04-03 11:00:00 AM','yyyy-mm- 
    dd hh:mi:ss pm') AND TO_DATE('2017-04-04 03:00:00 AM','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss 
    pm')
  )
AND TO_CHAR(row_creation,'DAY') NOT IN ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY')
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(row_creation,'W')`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify this, for whole April 2017, like here:

```
select * 
  from (
    select a.*, 
           count(case when cond='X' then 1 end) over (partition by trunc(row_creation-3/24)) cnt
      from table1 a
      where row_creation - 3/24 between date '2017-04-01' and date '2017-05-01'
        and to_char(row_creation, 'hh24') not between '03' and '10')
  where cnt = 0
```

where

```
row_creation - 3/24
```

assigns dates with hours `00:00` - `03:00` to previous day,

```
count(case when <cond> then 1 end) over (partition by trunc(row_creation - 3/24))
```

counts *unwanted* rows for this day, and finally:

```
where cnt = 0
```

is responsible for eliminating rows if there was at least one *unwanted* case for this day.

**<sup>[dbfiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3e8d8c00ef182ffd9a8f9e80a2b97ef2)</sup>**